# How to not save more then one data into a collection in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I don't want to save another data if there is already a data is present in that collection

Comment: What you have tried??

Comment: When new object inserted into mongoDb table, that record/object create itself _id to identify unique row. It's like primary key.

Comment: currently i am doing normally mongoose save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple implementation of how to prevent writing documents if there's already a document present in a Collection.

```
Collection.find( {}, (err, docs) => { // By not giving any arguments inside "{}", you tell MongoDB to return all the documents.
    if(docs) {  // If there are any documents already present in the Collection, this will become true and nothing will happen.
        return;
    } else {  // If there's no document already present in the Collection, new document will be added.
        Collection.save(doc);
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thanyou for answer!! If this question is helpfull for developer community then please accept the question by clicking up arrow.